# How to enjoy the Triage review when you are flag banned?

Tags: bug, status-completed, triage, flag-ban

I'm currently banned for flagging (for some low quality flag *mistakes*, <strike>with which I can live, never mind</strike>). What's worse is that it complicates the Triage review because the Unsalvageable button opens just the flag dialog, which is disabled for me with the message about my flagging failure:

[image]

And to be honest, I've been using it just for close voting so I would be actually using functionality that is not banned to me. But could not since the close dialog is *behind* this disabled one.

But, what makes me wonder is, will not this disabled dialog tend people to cheat on unsalvageable posts? At this time I can only Skip to the next question when I find an unsalvageable post. But, will the same all the flag banned users do? Shouldn't we rather disable the whole Triage if we'll keep using the flag functionality for Unsalvageable button?

Comment: I have used the discussion tag because this is quite philosofical problem. If we'll keep using existing flagging system for the Unsalvagable option, then we should probably disable the whole Triage for the flag suspended users since they are actually losing one of the 3 options.

Comment: Does anyone find objection to this being tagged as a bug?

Comment: @Compass: No, so i've (in Wikipedia philosophy) "Been Bold" and added the tag.

Comment: lol. highest reviewer on triage queue is martjin pieters. not exactly your average low rep joe.

Comment: Nothing wrong with triage review but it should be casting votes on your behalf, not throwing flags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll now be blocked from Triage review when you're flag-banned.

Comment: Plausible workaround (won't test it though :)