# Why am I banned after a single helpful flag after flag ban?

Tags: support, flag-ban

Till today morning [I was banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283162/960757) for flagging, then raised one flag which deemed helpful and I'm banned again.

[image]
[image]

Did I miss some which were waiting for review (if so, which are they), or is there something wrong with the system? I don't have any pending flags.

Comment: Your declined flags will balance out after a while. It easily happens, when you have some recently declined flags.

Comment: How long have you been banned?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243600/guaranteed-flag-ban

Comment: @BoltClock, 3 days, I think.

Comment: @BoltClock When enough of his declined flags age out; it shouldn't provide an exact time.

Comment: Why flag? You have other moderator tools that can be used more effectively. It seems you should be permanently banned from flagging if I understand the role of moderators.

Comment: @theMayer TLama is not a moderator.

Comment: We are all moderators to some extent, right? Higher rep = more moderator privileges?

Comment: @theMayer Yes, but that doesn't mean that people with high rep get every privilege that actual community moderators have. Flagging still has a purpose no matter what your rep level.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can only be banned from flagging if you have at least 10 flags in the past 7 days.  (To prevent your first flag being declined from resulting in a ban.)

When you cast a helpful flag you moved from 9 to 10 recent flags, resulting in the check being made to ensure you had a sufficiently high helpful percentage.  You failed that check.

Comment: IOW, the ban essentially becomes a rate-limit until you're far enough away from all of your declined flags.

Comment: I thought the threshold had been lowered to 6. Was it increased again?

Comment: @animuson  I hadn't heard it'd been lowered, but I haven't seen anything recent about this functionality at all.  If the limit is now 6 feel free to edit the post.

Comment: D'oh, I was mistaken by time. It counts (of course) the time when the flag is reviewed, not the time when you raise it. I'll wait then... [thanks for those who handled the posts I was going to flag]

Comment: Well, this is sort of counter-intuitive, isn't it?

Comment: @Servy: Limit was lowered to 6 per https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243601 , not sure if it was increased or not (so I didn't make the edit).

Comment: So wouldn't it be sensible of the "10 flags" was calculated as "10 unhelpful flags" instead of "any 10 flags"? Which would prevent this situation?

Comment: @PandaWood It would need to be like 3 unhelpful flags for it to be analogous, not 10.  Honestly I just don't think this is so much of a problem as to require re-working the system.  It doesn't come up very often, and its  not really a major problem when it does.

Comment: How about only running the check if the last flag was unhelpful?

Comment: @user763305 That's *exactly* what it currently is (well, it also has an "in the past 7 days" clause).  `x` is 10 and `y` is (I believe) 25%.  Given that check, someone can post 7 unhelpful flags, and then when they post 3 helpful flags they'll get flag banned.

Comment: @user763305 After your edit it's just a duplicate of [this earlier comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283396/why-am-i-banned-after-a-single-helpful-flag-after-flag-ban/283397?noredirect=1#comment141853_283397).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Agreed that its counter-intuitive. My feature-request to change that (see my linked Meta SE post on the question) has effectively been denied as "not worth fixing", and granted, there isn't *really* an easy fix as Shog points out.